# PHP: how to check if string is not numeric, but can contain spaces?

Tags: php, string

The goal is to validate a number that is numeric and may or may not contain spaces.

Eg, both '1800 123 456' and '1800123456' are acceptable.

Checking to see if it is not numeric is easy:

```
if(!is_numeric($phone_number)) {
  //display error message
}
```

But I am stuck as to how to pass it with spaces.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction with this?

Comment: How about removing all spaces before calling `is_numeric()`

Comment: @lionscribe I'd like to keep the spaces

Comment: You just remove the spaces in the variable passed to is_numeric, not the original value.

Comment: @lionscribe that's a good idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check without the spaces:

```
<?php
if(!is_numeric(str_replace(" ", "", $phone_number))) {
  //display error message
}
```

Or, if you want the overhead of a regular expression:

```
<?php
if (preg_match("/[^0-9 ]/", $phone_number)) {
    //display error message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/779359)

**Regex:** `^[\d]{4}\s+[\d]{3}\s+[\d]{3}|[\d]{10}$`

> `[\d]{4}\s+[\d]{3}\s+[\d]{3}` **Example:** Format of type this `1800 123 456`
>
> `[\d]{10}` **Example:** Format of type this `1800123456`

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$phone_number='1800 123 456';
if(preg_match("/^[\d]{4}\s+[\d]{3}\s+[\d]{3}|[\d]{10}$/",$phone_number)) 
{
     echo "matched";
}
else
{
     echo "not matched";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following checks:

```
//eliminate every char except 0-9
$justNums = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $string);

//eliminate leading 1 if its there
if (strlen($justNums) == 11) $justNums = preg_replace("/^1/", '',$justNums);

//if we have 10 digits left, it's probably valid.
if (strlen($justNums) == 10) $isPhoneNum = true;
```